# Kohanim hand symbol

Tags: kohen-priest, hands-fingers

When I was a kid I always heard that only kohanim are able to do the  hand position on both their hands. Leaving the “b-b-but I can do this and I’m not a kohen” comments aside, what’s the deal with this? Any basis in any sources? Old wives’ tale?

Comment: Refer to [Shibolei HaLeket, siman 23](https://www.sefaria.org/Shibbolei_HaLeket.23.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2878949/jewish/Is-the-Vulcan-Salute-a-Jewish-Symbol.htm

Comment: "Can" as in "physically capable", or "can" as in "allowed"?

Comment: @Shmuel physically

Comment: @CuriousYid You accepted an answer, but that answer doesn't seem to address this question, which is about non-kohanim possessing the physical ability to make the requisite hand formation. Am I understanding your question incorrectly?

Comment: @IsaacMoses the OP asked: "what’s the deal with this? Any basis in any sources?" - this can, and is be read by me as "what's the deal with this hand-gesture and is there any basis for this hand-gesture in any sources?".

Comment: @Shmuel It seems pretty clear to me that the "this" in "what's the deal with this" is "only kohanim are able to do the  hand position on both their hands," not "". If I'm wrong, then this question post needs to be edited to clearly express the latter instead of the former. If I'm right, then your answer doesn't address the question, and I don't understand why it was accepted.

Comment: I understand you @IsaacMoses and I ask the OP  to clarify what he means. If my answer does not answer the OP's question, I delete it :) But this is how I understood it, and I suppose that's what the OP asked for, since he accepted it.

Comment: @Shmuel @ Isaac Moses you guys are both right. I initially remember hearing that only kohanim were physically able to do it on both hands, but the answer clarified that it was just misphrased when I was younger, and rather anyone *can* do it but kohanim do in fact do it when they bless us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind it, can be found in several places, one of which is the Midrash Rabbah on [Shir HaShirim 2:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.2.9?lang=bi&p2=Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.2.9.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en). It explains that when the Kohanim bless, the Shechinah peers through their fingers so to speak.

Refer also to the [Tur in Orach Chaim, siman 128](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.128.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

The words  מציץ מן החרכים Meitzitz Min HaCharakim can also be read as "five cracks in the wall", which could mean that you should have five seperations between the fingers.

> One space below and between the thumbs, another two spaces between the thumb and second finger of each hand, and another two between the third and fourth finger of each hand (refer to [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2878949/jewish/Is-the-Vulcan-Salute-a-Jewish-Symbol.htm)) [(Shibolei HaLeket, siman 23)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shibbolei_HaLeket.23.2?vhe=Buber_Edition,_Vilna,_1886&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en).

The [Zohar in Bamidbar 147a](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1531346/jewish/Daily-Zohar-Naso-Day-5.htm) writes that for this reason, one should not look at the fingers of the Kohanim, since one should not be impudent towards the Shechinah.

Comment: Thank you Shmuel!

Comment: How can Metziz min HaHarakim be read as "five cracks in a wall"?
That would be "Hamisha Sdakim BaKir"

Comment: @user2962533 I think the article said that החרכים is read as ה חרכים, meaning 5 cracks

Comment: Mesiss min-ha'charakhim -- Suckling from the voices of those crying out in heaven-tearing yells calling out "Naaanaach!!"

Comment: Sparkling and flashing from the late bloomers that fell through the cracks of the system

Comment: Read it huchrakhim

Comment: @NissimNanach why do you in every comment and answer respond with these sentences like " Suckling from the voices of those crying out in heaven-tearing yells calling out "Naaanaach!!"?

Comment: @CuriousYid Oh, I see! I love these. Thank you!

Comment: @Shmuel You're right I don't see a direct relevance to the question with that reading I gave.

Comment: @use2962533 You get 5 from the Hei